# Is it ok to stop my serve when I've already started my racquet forward?

Tags: tennis, serve

In a match last night, I was serving, threw the ball in the air, and started swinging my racquet. Just before I hit the ball, I stopped my racquet and caught it because I didn't like the toss. Did I go too far? Should I have lost the point? Or is it ok to still stop my serve at that point?

I recorded the match. This is how close I got to hitting the ball before backing off.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this case is not considered a service fault.

From https://www.tennisgems.com/ball-toss/:

> the rules of tennis state that you are able to catch and redo your
>   ball toss during the tennis serve. If your racquet has not made
>   contact with the ball, you are allowed to try again.

From here: https://www.usta.com/content/dam/usta/sections/pacific-northwest/pdfs/play/leaguenew/ITFRuleswheader.pdf

> A player, who tosses the ball and then decides not to hit it, is
>   allowed to catch the ball with the hand or the racket, or to let the
>   ball bounce.

Answer (score 1):

**Should i have lost the point?** No. **Or its okay to skill stop my serve at that point?** Yes.

The rule is [cleary on this one](https://www.mogadouro.pt/uploads/writer_file/document/352/regras_tenis_16.pdf) (Portuguese language, page 10 - paragraph 19)

**Question:** *After throwing the ball into the air to perform the service, the server decides not to hit it and
instead take it. Is this a fault?*

**Answer:** No. A player who throws the ball in the air and then decides not to hit it is allowed catch it with your hand or racket or drop it on the floor.